# Take Negative of a Func<double[], double>

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, func

I have a mathematical function `-exp{-(x - 1)²} - exp{-0.5*(y - 2)²}` which is passed into an BFGS algorithm using the function and its derivatives

```
Func<double[], double> f = (x) => 
    Math.Exp(-Math.Pow(x[0] - 1, 2)) + Math.Exp(-0.5 * Math.Pow(x[1] - 2, 2));

Func<double[], double[]> g = (x) => new double[] 
{
    // df/dx = -2 * e^(-(x - 1)²)(x - 1).
    -2 * Math.Exp(-Math.Pow(x[0] - 1, 2)) * (x[0] - 1),

    // df/dy = -e^(-1/2(y - 2)²) * (y - 2).
    -Math.Exp(-0.5 * Math.Pow(x[1] - 2, 2)) * (x[1] - 2)
};
```

Now, the algorithm has been coded to minimise the function passed to it and this works great. However, I want to add the ability to maximise a function. To do this I will merely wrap the minimise code by negating the function and the derivatives and pass the result to the minimise code.

The ctor for the algo. is

```
public BroydenFletcherGoldfarbShanno(int numberOfVariables, 
    Func<double[], double> function, 
    Func<double[], double[]> gradient, 
    Random random = null)
        : this(numberOfVariables, random)
{
    if (function == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("function");
    if (gradient == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("gradient");
    this.Function = function;
    this.Gradient = gradient;
}
```

Which initialises the `Function`/`Gradient`. This class has a `Minimize` method and now I have added

```
public double Maximize()
{
     // Negate the function.
     Func<double[], double> f;
     f = (x) => -this.Function(x);
     this.Function = f;

     // Negate the derivatives.
     ...
}
```

My question is how can I merely negate the `this.Function`/`this.Gradient` objects? What I have done above throws a `StackOverflowException`.

Thanks for your time.

---

*Edit. with function declaration*

```
[TestMethod]
public void LBFGSMaximisationTest()
{
    // Suppose we would like to find the maximum of the function:
    // f(x, y) = exp{-(x - 1)²} + exp{-(y - 2)²/2}.
    // First we need write down the function either as a named
    // method, an anonymous method or as a lambda function.
    Func<double[], double> f = (x) =>
    Math.Exp(-Math.Pow(x[0] - 1, 2)) + Math.Exp(-0.5 * Math.Pow(x[1] - 2, 2));

    // Now, we need to write its gradient, which is just the
    // vector of first partial derivatives del_f / del_x.
    // g(x, y) = { del f / del x, del f / del y }.
    Func<double[], double[]> g = (x) => new double[] 
    {
        // df/dx = -2 * e^(-(x - 1)²)(x - 1).
        -2 * Math.Exp(-Math.Pow(x[0] - 1, 2)) * (x[0] - 1),

        // df/dy = -e^(-1/2(y - 2)²) * (y - 2).
        -Math.Exp(-0.5 * Math.Pow(x[1] - 2, 2)) * (x[1] - 2)
    };

    // Finally, we can create the L-BFGS solver, passing the functions as arguments.
    Random r = new SystemRandomSource(0, true);
    BroydenFletcherGoldfarbShanno lbfgs = new BroydenFletcherGoldfarbShanno(
        numberOfVariables: 2, function: f, gradient: g, random: r);

    // And then minimize the function.
    double maxValue = lbfgs.Maximize();
    ...
```

Comment: You don't show where `Function` is declared. This is important. Can you show this please?

Comment: I believe the `this.Function(x)` does not capture the function you expect it to - instead, I would think it uses the new value, eg. you'r doing Function = -Function, which again calls Function, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I have not had to do this before and it does not work as you expect it to...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will:

```
f = (x) => -this.Function(x);
this.Function = f;
```

Assuming that `Function`  is a `Funct<double[],double>` at the class level, you are basically writing:

```
this.Function = (x) => -this.Function(x);
```

so yeah, that will explode. This is because `this.Function` is deferred via captured scope. I suspect what you *mean* is:

```
Func<double[], double> oldFunc = this.Function;
this.Function = (x) => -oldFunc(x);
```

Now we're capturing the old function into a delegate, and using that captured delegate rather than call recursively.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I thought that in the attempt I showed above, that a 'new' object would be created and thus prevent that nasty circular reference. I will look up captured scope in this situation. Thanks for you time.

Comment: Marc, in the case of the gradient, there are two seperate expressions (for the two different directions) how would I go about negating those?